# JavaFX Multiple cellValueFactories for one tableRow?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I'm newish to JavaFX still and don't quite understand how factories work.

What I'm trying to do is both apply styling to a tableCell in a tableColumn depending on what the String value is, and also make the cell editable.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
    notesColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Computer, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null | empty)
            {
                setText(null);
                setStyle("");
            }
            else
            {
                setText(item);
                if (item.contains("Restoring @")) setTextFill(Color.CRIMSON);
                else if (item.contains("Ready")) setTextFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
                else setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    });
```

And this piece works as I'd like it to, but if I try to make the cell editable by using the below code, the cellFactories overwrite one another, of course. How do I combine the two?

```
 notesColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

Comment: Just make your custom cell implementation a subclass of `TextFieldTableCell` instead of a subclass of `TableCell`.

Comment: Could you clarify how I would do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really sure what there is to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
notesColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new TextFieldTableCell<Computer, String>(new DefaultStringConverter()) {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null | empty)
        {
            setStyle("");
        }
        else
        {
            if (item.contains("Restoring @")) setTextFill(Color.CRIMSON);
            else if (item.contains("Ready")) setTextFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
            else setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for!